# What is the base branch when a new one is created?

Tags: git, github, branch

I need to confirm/correct my assumptions when creating branches. If I'm in master branch, after doing:

```
git checkout -b some_branch
```

it means I have started a new branch from master.

On the other hand, if I checkout another branch, and create a branch there:

```
git checkout some_branch
git checkout -b other_branch
```

This means I've created other_branch using all the current code committed from some_branch, right?

And, regardless of the current branch, if this is done:

```
git branch branch_2 branch_1
```

Then branch_2 will be created using branch_1 as the base.
Are these assumptions correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. `branch` will only create the branch but will not `checkout`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is no such thing in Git as a *base branch* of a branch.  Instead, there is only a *current commit*, which Git calls the *tip of the branch*.

#### Drawing the graph

To understand this visually, as it were, you should start by drawing (at least part of) Git's *commit graph*.  Here's an example of a tiny repository with just three commits in it:

```
A <-B <-C   <--master
```

The "true name" of any given commit is one of those big ugly hash IDs, `c0ffeeface1deadbead...` and so on.  This hash ID uniquely identifies the specific commit, and in fact is *made* by hashing (hence the name "hash ID") the *contents* of that commit.  They look random and are impossible to remember, so here I just use single uppercase letters.

The way Git "sees" the graph is that it starts by reading a branch name, such as `master`.  This branch name contains the *hash ID* of a commit like `C`.  We say that `master` *points to* commit `C`.

Meanwhile, commit `C` itself contains the hash ID of its previous (or *parent*) commit `B`.  So we say that `C` points to `B`, the same way `master` points to `C`.

Likewise, commit `B` points back to `A`.  `A` is the very first commit ever, so there's nowhere for it to point back to ... so it just doesn't.  We call `A` a *root* commit, and it lets us (and Git) stop working backwards.

These internal arrows are kind of annoying to draw, and note that the hash ID of `B` is actually *part of* `C` itself, so it can never change (if we try to change this part of `C`, we get a new, *different* commit).  So we can stop bothering drawing them, and write instead:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

the arrow coming out of a *branch name*, though, is *not* constant, and that's where this whole idea of the *tip commit* comes from.

Suppose we want to add a new commit to `master`.  We do all the usual setup that Git requires (add or modify some files and use `git add`) and then run `git commit`.  Git:

- Writes out a new commit `D` (which gets a new, unique hash ID).  This new commit points back to `C`:

  ```
   A--B--C     <-- master
          \
           D
  ```
- Then, *changes* `master` (or more precisely, its stored hash ID) so that it points to the new commit we just made:

  ```
   A--B--C
          \
           D   <-- master
  ```

and of course there's no reason to keep this kink in the drawing anymore:

```
    A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

So this is how branches grow, in Git.

To make a *new* branch, Git simply creates the branch name *pointing to some existing commit*:

```
A
 \
  B
   \
    C
     \
      D   <-- master
```

We can pick any one of these commits and make a new branch name point there.  Let's pick `B` and make `newbr` point there:

```
A
 \
  B   <-- newbr
   \
    C
     \
      D   <-- master
```

We would do this with `git branch newbr <thing-that-finds-B>`.

#### But how do we find a commit?

How do we find `B`?  Well, one way is to run `git log` and cut-and-paste the hash ID.  But another way is to use a branch name.  The name `newbr` now points to `B`.  If we want to make another branch point to commit `B` too:

```
git branch thirdbr newbr
```

This makes Git look up `newbr`, which points to `B`, and create the new name `thirdbr`, which ... also points to `B`:

```
A--B   <-- newbr, thirdbr
    \
     C--D  <-- master
```

This is why creating a branch in Git is so bleeping fast: it does almost nothing at all!  It just makes a label that points to some existing commit.

The commit to which some branch-name points is called the *tip commit* of that branch.  Note that one commit can be the tip of several branches at the same time.  This is part of a larger thing about Git: some commits are on *many* branches, all at the same time.  For instance, commit `A`—the root commit—is on *every* branch.  (It's possible to have more than one root commit in a repository, although it's a bit tricky, and we don't need to worry about that now.  You can't do it with the commands shown this far.)

#### What makes branch names special

The special property of branch labels, though, is that they *move*.  Not only do they move, they move *automatically*.

We already saw this when we made new commit `D`.  Git wrote the new commit's ID into `master`.  But: **How did Git know to use `master`?**  For that matter, how did Git know to use `C` as the parent commit when Git made commit `D`?

Well, of course we only had one branch at the time, but let's make a new commit *now*, now that we have three labels `master`, `newbr`, and `thirdbr`.  First, though, let's do `git checkout thirdbr`, and draw the result:

```
A--B   <-- newbr, thirdbr (HEAD)
    \
     C--D  <-- master
```

Nothing really changed in the drawing,<sup>1</sup> except that I added the word `HEAD` here.  HEAD is how Git knows which branch-and-commit are the *current* branch and commit.

So now we do our usual modify-some-files, `git add`, and `git commit`.  Git writes out the new commit, with its parent set to commit `B`.  Git sees that the *current* branch is `thirdbr` and `thirdbr` points to `B`, so the current *commit* is `B`.  Let's draw in the new commit `E`:

```
     E
    /
A--B   <-- newbr
    \
     C--D  <-- master
```

The only thing left is to move the current branch *name* `thirdbr` so that it points to new commit `E`:

```
     E   <-- thirdbr (HEAD)
    /
A--B   <-- newbr
    \
     C--D  <-- master
```

and we're all done: we've added a new commit to branch `thirdbr` (which is still HEAD, and hence still the current branch, but now `E` is the current commit).

**When you add a commit to the current branch, it's HEAD that tells what the current commit was and where the new commit goes.**  HEAD normally contains the name of a branch, and that's what `git checkout` does: it checks out a specific commit—usually, the tip commit of an existing branch—and then sets up the file `HEAD` to remember the *name* of the branch.  It's the branch name itself that remembers the *tip commit*.

Using `git checkout -b newname commit` means: "check out the specified *commit*, then make a new branch name *newname* that points to that commit, and then set HEAD to that new name."  If you leave out the *commit* part, the default is to use HEAD.  Since HEAD *is* (always) the current commit, Git gets to skip the "check out" part and just create the new branch name and store it into the `HEAD` file.

---

<sup>1</sup>While nothing changed in the *graph*, Git did have to update our work-tree, and the *index*, so that we could have the files as of the way they were at commit `B`.

Comment: just wondering what the HEAD would contain if it is in detached mode?

Comment: @MKYung: in that case, it holds a raw hash ID. Instead of having to do `HEAD` -> branch -> hash, Git just does `HEAD` -> hash. Instead of `git commit` doing hash -> `HEAD` -> branch, `git commit` just writes the new hash into `HEAD`.

Comment: There is documentation on github and other sources that refer to 'base' branches...