# Base vs default branch in bitbucket version of git

Tags: git, bitbucket

Why there exists two different types of branches, base and default in Bitbucket? In my mind I understand that the master branch most of the times should be the default branch, i.e. the branch that everyone in the team should use as a reference and as also the branch that "guidelines" the development. But what different functionality a base branch may introduce? Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In Bitbucket, the **base branch** is the last branch that you have selected from the list of branches. If you select another branch in the drop-down menu, you will see how the "base branch" icon moves to the newly selected one.

In Git itself, there is no base branch concept. This was answered in [What is the base branch when a new one is created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550302/what-is-the-base-branch-when-a-new-one-is-created)

The **default branch** is `master` (you will be on this branch after a clone or when browsing a repository). In Bitbucket you can change the default branch in the Repository Settings screen.

Comment: Adding to dokaspar's nice answer, it also seems that defining a ***base*** branch can give you at a given time a different ***view*** with respect to ***how much Behind/Ahead*** are the rest of your branches according to your defined base branch at that given time.

Answer (score 2):

When you `git checkout -b mybranch`, `mybranch` becomes the default branch. You always have to supply a target branch as there is no other branch object to reference. You can set up aliases or bash functions to create the same functionality as 'Base Branch', supplying a default target branch, on the command line.

Why "*base branch*" exists... Depending on you branching model, if you are doing a quarterly release, you may be doing the majority of your feature development against a long-lived branch `q2-release` for example. As features are merged into `q2-release`, you will want to diff to that branch instead of `master`. A diff against `master` may be unhelpful as it was the last quarter's release and missing the current changes for the next release candidate.